# close active infowindows from external link google maps api v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I am working on a website with google maps integrated.
http://www.ecompanies.nl/pilot/webdesign/breda.html

Infowindows can be opened by clicking on a map marker, or on a header link in the items listed on the right. How can I close the active infowindow before opening a new one (by clicking on a map marker, or on a header link)?

Thanks in advance.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new infowindow for each marker. The best way to achieve what you want is to create one infowindow and share that between all the markers.

So:

1. Put the infowindow creation before the loop.
2. When you create the click event listener for the marker in the loop add `infowindow.setContent('content');` before you open the marker.

this will automatically close the infowindow and open it over the new marker

Comment: Hi..
Thank you so much.
I saw it in the documentation before but couldn't make it work.
Followed your instructions and now I got it running..
Thanks!!